# Titlesec issue with table of contents and starred chapters

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, titlesec, starred-version

I would like to know why the following code prints the header "CONTENTS" after chapter 1 (Intro) starts, instead of writing the correct chapter name "Intro" in the header (as it does for chapter 2 "Test"). Do I need to patch "titlesec"?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newpagestyle{main}{%
  \headrule
  \sethead{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{}{\chaptertitle}
  \setfoot{}{}{\thepage}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{intro}
b \newpage b
\chapter{test}
a \newpage b
\end{document}
```

Comment: @JamesT : right, but it doesn't change the problem: "contents" still appears in the header of chapter 1...

Comment: The comment above was to add `\pagestyle{main}`

Comment: This is the default behavior in LaTeX. You need a combination of `\chaptermark` and, very likely, `\ifthesection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, LaTeX doesn’t update headers and footers with starred sectioning commands. You have do it yourself with `\chaptermark` (avoid `\markboth` and `\markright`). In addition, you may want to remove the chapter numbers, which is accomplished with `\ifthechapter`. Don’t forget the package option `pagestyles`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\newpagestyle{main}{%
  \headrule
  \sethead{\ifthechapter{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{}}{}{\chaptertitle}
  \setfoot{}{}{\thepage}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{main}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{intro}
\chaptermark{intro}
b \newpage b
\chapter{test}
a \newpage b
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that `\chapter*` does not reset or change the running head. KOMA-Script classes provide command `\addchap` resp. `\addsec` for this purpose:

```
\documentclass[headings=standardclasses,headsepline,cleardoublepage=headings]{scrbook}

% Following lines are only to make a similar heading like your `\newpagestyle` definition but using KOMA-Script
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{chapter}

\clearscrheadfoot
\renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markdouble{\MakeMarkcase{\Ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}\hfill#1}}%
}
\ohead{\headmark}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{intro}% Chapter with ToC entry and running head
b \newpage b
\chapter{test}
a \newpage b
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the standard classes, you would need an additional `\markboth`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newpagestyle{main}{%
  \headrule
  \sethead{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{}{\chaptertitle}
  \setfoot{}{}{\thepage}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{intro}% does neither add a ToC entry nor change the running head
\markboth{into}{into}
b \newpage b
\chapter{test}
a \newpage b
\end{document}
```

[image]

But this does not work as expected using a `titleps` (`titlesec`) pagestyle. So here is an example without `titlesec` but using `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\documentclass{book}

% Following lines are only to make a similar heading like your `\newpagestyle` definition but using KOMA-Script
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{chapter}

\clearscrheadfoot
\renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markdouble{\MakeMarkcase{\chaptermarkformat\hfill#1}}%
}
\ohead{\headmark}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{intro}% does neither add a ToC entry nor change the running head
\markboth{into}{into}
b \newpage b
\chapter{test}
a \newpage b
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Your second solution does not work well if we add `\pagestyle{main}` (which I forgot...)

Comment: @Watson This is a `titleps` (loaded by `titlesec`) problem, but I do not know `titleps` good enough, to solve it. I always use `scrlayer-scrpage` and know a little bit about `fancyhdr` but never use `titleps`. See my third example, how `scrlayer-scrpage` could be used.

Comment: Yes. Ideally I would like a solution which "fixes" this issue of `titlesec`. I could add this issue to https://github.com/jbezos/titlesec/issues